# Highcharts - Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to remove the white border when one segment of the pie chart is at 100%.I have this problem only on Firefox (v19 and v20 on WIN7 and MAC OSX) and Mobile Safari (iOS5 and iOS6).

I have tried this:

```
plotOptions: {
  pie: {
    borderWidth: 0
  }
}
```

But the white border is visible. You can show my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KNFJE/33/

Do You have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/KNFJE/34/ please check if it what you wanted

Comment: no i mean this line on top http://s14.directupload.net/images/130513/qv7ajkcu.png

Comment: thats what is gone did you check the updated fiddle??

Comment: Issue reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1828 Thanks!